# UICollectionviewのセルのタップを優先させたい。

Tags: swift, xcode

UIViewに

①UICollectionviewをaddSubviewして、

②UITapGestureRecognaizerをaddGestureRecognizerしている

状態で、

collectionViewのセルのタップに失敗した（特定のセルがタップされなかったなど）場合に
②のtapが反応するようにしたいです。

上の状態だと、②が先に反応してしまいます。

---

ご回答ありがとうございます。

下のように記述すると、
なぜだか、viewのどこをタップしても、pointの値が一定になります。

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {


        let point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(gestureRecognizer.view)
        let convertLocation = gestureRecognizer.view!.convertPoint(point, toView: currentCardView!.cv)
        let indexPath = currentCardView!.cv.indexPathForItemAtPoint(convertLocation)
        if indexPath != nil {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`を実装して以下のような判定を行います。

Swift3の記述ですが、Swift2でもデリゲートメソッドの体裁以外は特に変わりません。

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: touch.location(in: self.collectionView)) != nil {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

`GestureRecognaizer`のタッチ座標から、`UICollectionView`の`indexPath`を取得します。

取得できた場合、どこかのセルの座標なので、`false`を返します。これにより、`UICollectionViewCell`のタップイベントが優先して実行されます。

`nil`が返却された場合は、セルのない座標なので`true`を返却して`GestureRecognaizer`のイベントを実行します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！納得いたしました。ただ上に追記したのですが、pointがうまくとれません。何か間違っているでしょうか？

Comment: @forest `gestureRecognizer.view`は、`UIGestureRecognizer`が紐付いている`UIView`なので固定値になってしまいますね。タッチ座標の取得には、`UIGestureRecognizer`のデリゲートメソッドで渡される`UITouch`の座標を使う必要があります。

Comment: 出来ました！ありがとうございます！